# Is it possible to reference while recurring to anonymous function in scheme ?

Tags: scheme

I try to write function which add some number to every element in the list and then makes sum of all this terms.

```
 (define (num-to-sumtup num)
  (lambda (tup)
    (cond
     ((null? tup) 0)
     (else (+ (car tup) num (num-to-sumtup ())) ;; here I need to get reference on the inner function
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make it a anonymous procedure. It may have a name in the scope of `num-to-sumtup`. Here are some examples of ways to do it. The simples way to do this would be to use the `rec` syntax which is defined in the [SRFI-31](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html).

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (srfi :31))

(define (num-to-sumtup num)
  (rec (recur tup)
    (cond
     ((null? tup) 0)
     (else (+ (car tup) num (recur (cdr tup)))))))

((num-to-sumtup 10) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; ==> 65
```

You can also do this with `define`:

```scm
(define (num-to-sumtup num)
  (define (sum-list tup)
    (cond
     ((null? tup) 0)
     (else (+ (car tup) num (sum-list (cdr tup))))))

  sum-list); we return the locally named procedure
```

Using higher order procedures and `cut` from [SRFI-26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html).

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs lists) ; fold-left
        (srfi :26))  ; cut

(define (num-to-sumtup num)
  (lambda (tup)
    (fold-left (cut + <> <> num) 0 tup)))
```

Comment: You are much ahead of me :)

Comment: Do you have blog or something where you can suggest a proper learning path for acquiring knowledge like you do have?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev Unfortunately not. The good stuff, like [the wizards themselves demonstrating the power of Scheme](https://youtu.be/2Op3QLzMgSY?list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46), is using an older version of the standard. However I would start there anyway. [The report documents](http://www.r6rs.org/) are tedious, but it's the best source of the standard. If you already know another language you should try to implement a lisp interpreter in it, perhaps after reading about the [creator of the first Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html). Answer questions here for a while and you're an expert.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. `num-to-sumtup` Takes a number as argument, and returns a function, that takes a list. So you execute it to get the function, and then execute that function.

```
 (define (num-to-sumtup num)
  (lambda (tup)
    (cond
     ((null? tup) 0)
     (else
      (+ (car tup) num ((num-to-sumtup num) (cdr tup)))))))
;Value: num-to-sumtup

((num-to-sumtup 10) '(1 2 3 4 5))
;Value: 65
```

In the spirit of sylwester's answer here's another option

```
(define (num-to-sup num)
  (lambda (tup)
    (foldl (lambda (x y) (+ num x y)) 0 tup)))
```